# Jquery click no triggering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a while loop to create a table and I am trying to pass a unique value stored in a php variable called `$i` to a jquery ajax call but all I get returned it `'undefined'`.

The portion of the html table (whole table is wrapped in a `div` called `audit_content` which is not part of the while loop)

```
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
          <input type="button" class="delete_submit delete_from_audit" name="image_delete" value="" 
               onClick="delete_image('<? echo $image_id; ?>','<? echo $audit_id; ?>')" />
          <input type="button" class="reset_grade control_submit ie7_reset" 
               onclick="reset_image('<? echo $image_id; ?>','<? echo $audit_id; ?>')" value="" >
          <input type="hidden" class="form_id" value="<? echo $i; ?>" >
          <input type="button" name="audit_submit"
            class="audit_submit audit_submit_btn ie7_submit" value=""; />
      </td>
  </tr>
```

the Jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function(){
        var form_id = $(this).next('.form_id').val();
        alert(form_id);
           //$.ajax({
           //type: "POST",
           //url: "ajax/image_audit.php",
           //data: $('#audit_form').serialize()
        //});
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.form_id` element is before the `.audit_submit` button... Try `prev()` instead of `next()`:

```
var form_id = $(this).prev('.form_id').val();
```

You could also use `siblings()`:

```
var form_id = $(this).siblings('.form_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".audit_submit", function(){
        var form_id = $(this).next('.form_id').val();
        alert(form_id);
           //$.ajax({
           //type: "POST",
           //url: "ajax/image_audit.php",
           //data: $('#audit_form').serialize()
        //});
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="button" name="audit_submit"
        class="audit_submit audit_submit_btn ie7_submit" value=""**---> ; <----** />
```

Why is there a semi colon ?? 
Php will consider it as the end of the statement.

Comment: just as well it isn't written in php then